# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 784)

Tags: python, opencv

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import math


def process(img_input):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_input, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.resize(gray, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    (thresh, img_binary) = cv2.threshold(
        gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    h, w = img_binary.shape
    ratio = 100 / h
    new_h = 100
    new_w = w * ratio

    img_empty = np.zeros((110, 110), dtype=img_binary.dtype)
    img_binary = cv2.resize(
        img_binary, (int(new_w), int(new_h)), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img_empty[:img_binary.shape[0], :img_binary.shape[1]] = img_binary
    img_binary = img_empty

    cnts = cv2.findContours(
        img_binary.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    M = cv2.moments(cnts[0][0])
    center_x = (M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    center_y = (M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    height, width = img_binary.shape[:2]
    shiftx = width / 2 - center_x
    shifty = height / 2 - center_y

    Translation_Matrix = np.float32([[1, 0, shiftx], [0, 1, shifty]])
    img_binary = cv2.warpAffine(
        img_binary, Translation_Matrix, (width, height))

    img_binary = cv2.resize(img_binary, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    flatten = img_binary.flatten() / 255.0
    return flatten


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                           input_shape=(100, 100, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

model = load_model('model3.h5')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

while (True):

ret, img_color = cap.read()

if ret == False:
    break

img_input = img_color.copy()
cv2.rectangle(img_color, (250, 150),
              (width - 250, height - 150), (0, 0, 255), 3)
cv2.imshow('bgr', img_color)

img_roi = img_input[150:height - 150, 250:width - 250]

key = cv2.waitKey(1)

if key == 27:
    break
elif key == 32:
    flatten = process(img_roi)

    predictions = model.predict(flatten[np.newaxis, :])

    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        print(tf.argmax(predictions, 1).eval())

    cv2.imshow('img_roi', img_roi)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/TOTOYAA/Desktop/mnist/34.py", line 98, in <module>
    predictions = model.predict(flatten[np.newaxis, :])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1629, in predict
    tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 726, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3206, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1478 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1468 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1461 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1434 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Seongwoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:239 assert_input_compatibility
        str(tuple(shape)))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 784)

[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-fgndhvyk\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I had ran my Camera Code, I got error like Title.
`(predictions = model.predict(flatten[np.newaxis, :]))` line got error.

Please provide me some help.

Comment: Format your code, so it'll be easy for people to run it and check.

Comment: Elaborate on what you're doing in process function. Your process function returns (784,) shape array and your model expects (100, 100, 3) image. So the process function is not even returning an image.